# videoRecording Failed The camera device has encountered a serious error

Tags: android, flutter, video, camera, android-camera

I have these errors at my screen while I stopped the video { I am using flutter, and https://pub.dev/packages/camera
camera: ^0.5.8+11
} Any idea how to fix it? Thanks.

> Camera error The camera device has encountered a fatal error flutter

> Error: videoRecording Failed The camera device has encountered a serious error

**my code when video stopped:**

```
 void stopVideoRecording() async {
try {
  await cameraController.stopVideoRecording();

} on CameraException catch (e) {
  _showCameraException(e);
  return null;
}

Navigator.pushNamed(context, TutorApplicationVideoSubmitScreen.path,
    arguments: videoPath);
```

}

And the error in log:

```
I/MediaRecorder(20839): stop
E/[EGL-ERROR](20839): void __egl_platform_dequeue_buffer(egl_surface*):1734: failed to dequeue buffer from native window 0x5587d0d1f0; err = -19, buf = 0x0,max_allowed_dequeued_buffers 3
 
E/CameraDeviceGLThread-1(20839): Received exception on GL render thread: 
E/CameraDeviceGLThread-1(20839): java.lang.IllegalStateException: swapBuffers: EGL error: 0x300d
E/CameraDeviceGLThread-1(20839):    at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.checkEglError(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:530)
E/CameraDeviceGLThread-1(20839):    at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.swapBuffers(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:523)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using `camera: 0.5.8+11` This error already fixed. Please upgrade the package to the latest version which is `0.6.4+3`.

refer: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72994